# Display related topics base on Wordpress and BBpress tags?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, categories, bbpress

I have a question on how to display related topics based on WordPress and BBpress tags. I'm currently able to display latest topics, but not related to the article.

```
<div class="bbp-related">
    <?php
        $topics_post = array('author'=> 0, 'post_type'=>bbp_get_topic_post_type(), 'post_parent'=>$parent_forum, 'posts_per_page'=>3, 'post_status'=>join(',', array(bbp_get_public_status_id(), bbp_get_closed_status_id())), 'show_stickes'=>false, 'meta_key'=>'_bbp_last_active_time', 'orderby'=>'meta_value', 'order'=>'DESC', 'meta_query'=>array(bbp_exclude_forum_ids('meta_query')));
    ?>
    <?php $widget_query = new WP_Query($topics_post); ?>
    <?php   while ($widget_query->have_posts()) :
        $widget_query->the_post();
        $topic_id = bbp_get_topic_id($widget_query->post->ID);
    ?>
        <li>
            <?php bbp_author_link( array( 'post_id' => 1, 'size' => 100 ) ); ?>
            <a class="bbp-title" href="<?php bbp_topic_permalink($topic_id); ?>" title="<?php bbp_topic_title($topic_id); ?>"><?php bbp_topic_title($topic_id); ?></a>
            <p><?php bbp_topic_excerpt($topic_id); ?></p>
            <span class="reply"><?php bbp_forum_reply_count(); ?> Balasan</span>
            <span class="reply-date"><?php bbp_reply_post_date(0, true); ?></span>
        </li>
        <?php   endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

The above code currently display 3 latest topics. What I want is to display a related topics base on Tags or Categories. How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: One idea would be to query for the tags and return all posts you find for that. But you should probably think about some kind of "sorting system", so you have more relevant topics at the top of your list. Maybe have a look at how other plugins handle this, there should be some on the WordPress repository.

Comment: thanks for reply! Do you have a code ideas? I've trying adapt from plugins but not workinf :(

Comment: Not really, sorry. You can make this very complex or very easy, just as you like. Easy would be: Query for all tags, sort them by date and show the last three. But that might be too rudimentary in the end.

Comment: Anyone else can help me?